# Virtual Machine on top of hypervisor(which is on bare metal) without host operating system

Tags: virtualization

Suppose I have a bare metal on which I put Hypervisor. And then I put Oracle Virtual box (which has Linux OS in it).
Is it possible to do this ie is it possible to have a virtual box on top of hypervisor without the host OS on my bare metal hardware?

Comment: Yes, but you need the right kind of hypervisor that supports that. Do you have a specific one in mind? Or are you planning to make one?

Comment: Stack overflow is specifically for programming questions, so unless you are thinking of making the hypervisor, this is probably off-topic here.

Comment: I got the answer , we have bare metal hypervisors for it.Since I am new ,where can I ask questions which are not related to programming but are related to Computer Science? Thank you.

Comment: I’m not sure, but perhaps http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com.